# Showing numpy array as image with animation

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a 2D numpy array which I want to show as an image. Now using matplotlib `plt.imshow(my_array)` works fine. The problem is that my array keeps on changing. There is a function `foo()` which changes the array. I want to show that array as image and also the changes done by foo function. It should be only one image window and the updates are done in that window instead of creating new one. `FuncAnimation` is one way but it is used with plots. How can I use it to show image?

My image is actually an arena of obstacles. I am trying to show path finding and visualise it. Breadth-First Search and Dijkstra's algorithm I am trying to visualise.

Kindly help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing how your code is structured but one solution to your problem could be using  `plt.pause()`

An example,

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def draw_me(img):
    plt.pause(.01)
    plt.imshow(img)

for idx in range(12):
    img = np.random.randint(0, 255, (12,12))
    draw_me(img)
```

**note** if you are using Sypder make sure you're not inline ploting in the console. For me that means entering the following in the console,

```
%matplotlib auto
%matplotlib qt
```

Comment: This too serves my purpose. However I have used OpenCV to show images. Thank you for this answer. Marking it correct in case someone comes up with similar question.